# Angular9 reusable multi-autocomplete-chips input as FormArray / ERROR TypeError: control.registerOnChange is not a function

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular2-formbuilder, controlvalueaccessor

### Condition

*Table component* - table with row create/edit button. On click at any of these buttons same *Dialog component* with input field is opened. *Input* field is a reusable multi-autocomplete-chips *component*. If user clicks "edit row", given values must be set into input field as mat-chips and remain editable (delete chip(s) or add new). If "create row" is chosen - empty input, user may add new.

### Problem

When I open edit-dialog I do have values from table set to the input field. But with it I get an error:

> ERROR TypeError: control.registerOnChange is not a function

There is a connection between dialog-component and input-component what I can't understand. I assume the problem is somewhere in **FormControl** and **ControlValueAccessor**.

### Code

dialog.component.ts:

```ts
    this.fb.group({
                *here are some working FormControls*,
                managers: this.fb.array(this.someInterface.managers)
```

dialog.component.html:

```html
                <managers-auto-chips-selector
                        formControlName="managers">
                </managers-auto-chips-selector>
```

input.component.html:

```html
    <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
                <mat-label>Manager</mat-label>
                <mat-chip-list #chipList>
                    <mat-chip
                            *ngFor="let item of selectedList"
                            [selectable]="selectable"
                            [removable]="removable"
                            (removed)="remove(item)">
                        {{item.name}}
                        <mat-icon matChipRemove *ngIf="removable">cancel</mat-icon>
                    </mat-chip>
                    <input matInput
                           placeholder="Manager"
                           #managerInput
                           [matAutocomplete]="autocomplete"
                           [formControl]="managerControl"
                           [matChipInputFor]="chipList"
                           [matChipInputSeparatorKeyCodes]="separatorKeysCodes"
                           [matChipInputAddOnBlur]="addOnBlur"
                           (matChipInputTokenEnd)="add($event)">
                </mat-chip-list>

                <mat-autocomplete #autocomplete="matAutocomplete" (optionSelected)="selected($event)">
                    <mat-option *ngFor="let item of filteredList | async" [value]="item">
                        {{ item.name }}
                    </mat-option>
                </mat-autocomplete>
            </mat-form-field>
```

input.component.ts (added):

```ts
    filteredList: Observable<Manager[]>;
    list: Manager[] = [];  <--- managers list filled from API
    selectedList: Manager[] = [];
    managerControl = new FormControl();
    constructor( @Optional() @Self() public ngControl: NgControl) {
    if (this.ngControl != null) {
         this.ngControl.valueAccessor = this;
       }
    }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.filteredList = this.managerControl.valueChanges.pipe(
            map((manager: string | null) => {
                return manager ? this._filter(manager) : 
              this.list.slice();
            })
        );

        this.getManagersList();
    }
    private _filter(value: any): any[] {

        return this.list.filter(manager => {
            if (typeof value === 'string') {
                return manager.fio.toLowerCase().includes(value.toLowerCase());
            } else {
                return manager.fio.toLowerCase().includes(value.fio.toLowerCase());
            }
        });
    }
    add(event: MatChipInputEvent): void {
        const input = event.input;
        const value = event.value;

        // Add our fruit
        if ((value || '').trim()) {

            const item = this.list.filter(manager => {
                return manager.fio.toLowerCase().includes(value.toLowerCase());
            });

            if (item.length === 1) {
                this.selectedList.push(item[0]);
            }
        }

        // Reset the input value
        if (input) {
            input.value = '';
        }

        this.managerControl.setValue(null);
    }
    selected(event: MatAutocompleteSelectedEvent): void {
        this.selectedList.push(event.option.value);
        this.managerInput.nativeElement.value = '';
        this.managerControl.setValue(null);
    }

    registerOnChange(fn: any): void {
    }

    registerOnTouched(fn: any): void {
    }

    writeValue(item: any): void {
       this.selectedList = item;
    }
```

I have several suggestions where to move next, but any of them drags my away from the result I have at the moment. 
Still:

1) In dialog.component.html `formControlName` to `formArrayName`. If I do it, error doesn't appear, but my values arent set and I have blank input.
2) In input.component.ts `managerControl = new FormControl()` to `new FormArray([ ])`. Then I got few(!) error messages:

> ERROR TypeError: control.registerOnChange is not a function

3) Something to put into `registerOnChange` function. Can't get it.
4) Somehow push every single FormControl from dialog.components.ts `managers: this.fb.array(this.someInterface.managers)` to  `managerControl = new FormArray([]);`
5) ???

Any comments or advice is appreciated.
Any deeper explanation, extra code or screenshots will be provided on demand.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Some code about how you populate the form would've been very useful.

Use FormArray instead of FormControl for `managers` property. If your values aren't set then you're doing it wrong.

Below you can find an example of how you could do it and adapt it for your use case:

```js
ngOnInit() {
 this.myForm = this.fb.group({
      ...
      managers: this.fb.array([], Validators.required),
    });

  this.myService.getWhatever().subscribe(whatever => {
    if(whatever) {
      this.myForm.setValue({
       ...
      // set it to an empty array
      managers: [] 
     });

     // push the data that you get to the form array
     for (const manager of whatever.managers) {
        this.managers.push(new FormControl(manager));
      }
   }
 }
}

 // Getter for retrieving the tags form array control from the parent form group
  public get managers(): FormArray {
    return this.myForm.get('managers') as FormArray;
  }
```

```html
<mat-chip-list #chipList formArrayName="managers">
  <mat-chip 
    *ngFor="let manager of managers.controls; index as i"
   >
     {{ manager.name }}
    <mat-icon matChipRemove *ngIf="removable">cancel</mat-icon>
  </mat-chip>
</mat-chip-list>
```

Comment: More input.component.ts code added. Apparently, I should separate your code among modal.component and (reusable) input.component. Form, where input used is located in modal-component, but whole logic of input is stored in input-component. How exactly? Else, should I remove existing `[formControl]="managerControl"` from input field in input.ts (I thought it counts like single `FormControl` in input for each element)?

Comment: @BlyzniukYevhen sorry for the late reply. You can pass the managers array from the input as a property to the dialog component. It's not a form control, it's a form array so you need to loop over. If you create a stackblitz with a minimal representation I might be able to help you further.